# Format friendly Date using android-databinding approach

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I would like to format my date YYYY/MM/DD to more friendly mode.

I use android-databinding.

my expects output should be example: Tuesday, 22 August 2006.
My Current input from Json is "2018-09-27" (String data in model)

my code:

```
public class DateUtils {

SimpleDateFormat fromServer = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

   public String getDateToFromat  (String reciveDate)  {
       String newFormatString = myFormat.format(fromServer.parse(reciveDate));
 return newFormatString;
   };

}
```

my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data class ="CurrencyBindingDetailItem">
        <import type="com.example.htw.currencyconverter.utils.DateUtils"/>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable name="currencyItemDetailDate" type="com.example.htw.currencyconverter.model.CurrencyDate"/>
        <variable name="currencyBindingItemDetail" type="com.example.htw.currencyconverter.model.CurrencyBinding"/>
        <variable name="callback" type="com.example.htw.currencyconverter.callback.ClickCallback"/>
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:text="@{DateUtils.getDateToFromat(currencyItemDetailDate.date)}"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

and I do have error:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:**cannot find method getDateToFromat**(java.lang.String) in class com.example.htw.currencyconverter.utils.DateUtils
```

I did clean and restart and rebuild.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you create a databinding adapter, so your xml stays clearer? Since your date from the server is in string format, adapter will look like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("bindServerDate")
public static void bindServerDate(@NonNull TextView textView, String date) {
    /*Parse string data and set it in another format for your textView*/
}
```

The usage of it:

In your viewModel create `ObservableField<String> serverDate` and set the value from your response, in xml set `app:bindServerDate="@{viewModel.serverDate}"`. Don't forget to add `viewModel` as `variable` and set it from your `activity/fragment`

Comment: I will try this way, THX !

Answer (score 1):

You need two `DateFormat` objects. One to format the string you received from the server, and another to your desired format.

```
SimpleDateFormat fromServer = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
String inputDateStr="2018-09-27";
Date date = fromServer.parse(inputDateStr);
String outputDateStr =myFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: for better code view I do not leave a comment but send a answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @BindingAdapter("formatDate")
fun TextView.setDate(order_date: String) {
    var outputDate: String? = null
    try {
        val curFormater = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
        val postFormater = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")

        val dateObj = curFormater.parse(order_date)
        outputDate = postFormater.format(dateObj)
        this.setText(outputDate)

    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```